# target and window open not working together in IE

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to open a new window onclick of a link. This submits the form and should open the window defined in target.
I am successful in doing it in chrome and FF but not in IE.
Below is my code:

```
  <form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="get" action="${URL_DOCUMENT}">

<table border=1 cellpadding=1 width="50%" style='table-layout: fixed'
  id="table1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
              <th align='left'>Statement Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="statement" items="${list}">
              <tr>
                    <td><a href="" onclick="return callSubmit(this)">
                    <c:out value="${statement.date}" /> <img
                          src='/images/dat.png'
                          alt="" style="border-style: none"> </a></td>
              </tr>
        </c:forEach>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input type="hidden" name="key" id="key" value="" /></form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function callSubmit(link){

  var test =link.innerHTML.split("<");
  document.getElementById("key").value = test[0]; 
  var w =  window.open('','newDocWin','width=500,height=300,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no'); 

 document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
 return false;
 }
 </script>
```

In IE 2 windows are getting opened up. The window that I defined and another(not sure from where it is coming). In chrome and FF it is working fine(PDF response in defined window.)
**Am I doing anything wrong here?**

Comment: It doesn't look like you have all of your code available in the question. Can you also format it as code for easier reading?

Comment: Remove the "target" attribute from form, it might be the cause of opening 2nd window.

Comment: without target attribute, the response will be rendered in the same form. I need the response in a customized window

Answer (score 0):

Can it be as simple as this?

```
 <form action="demo_form.php" method="get" target="_blank">
```

Comment: target="_blank" will not open a customized window. I need a customized window which has the response.